# HttpListener only works on local network

Tags: c#, .net, networking, httplistener

I am not a networking guy, please excuse any ignorance, so I have a netgear R7000 have the dyndms set and when I ping the host address I get the same ip as when I google what's my ip.

I have registered the port, temporarily put my computer in the dmz and turned off windows firewall(only firewall on the machine).

A little background, ISP is Comcast(non static up hence the problem), disabled the firewall on the router/modem and have the R7000 router in the dmz of the Comcast router/modem.

Am I trying to do something that is not possible or missing something obvious?

Does my httprequest need to have any headers to make it through noip or my router?

**Edit:** As per Don's comment I put my computer running a webserver in the DMZ of my Comcast router.  Still no dice, however I discovered that when connected to the Comcast router my IP reports as IPv6.  I suspect this is what is causing my problem, however it is flying way over my head.  I am running a proof of concept app using HttpClient and HttpRequestMessage to test the webserver.  I can still connect on the local network but nothing from outside.  Any and all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I assume you're trying to access your PC from the internet?
And coming from the internet you trying to have it route past two routers, first Comcasts and then the R7000?
First make sure you can access your PC from in your local network directly. (What app are you trying to access it with? or are you hosting a webserver or somthing?)
Also, until you change the IP, DynDns will continue to point to your IP, so, temporarily try to remove the R7000 from the equation and put your PC directly into the Comcast DMZ - to see if that works first.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will be sure to try that tomorrow when I get back to the pc.  I am hosting a web server on the pc and have a proof of concept application i created communicating with it, I can communicate with the server from a windows phone on the same Network, will update with results tomorrow.